# Where is the right place for annotation processing?

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I write simple application. I don't want to use any frameworks. Please suggest me right place to hold annotation processing.

I have a few lines in `main` method:

```
String myString = (@NonNull String)list;
```

And I created `@interface`:

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE_USE, ElementType.TYPE_PARAMETER})
public @interface NonNull {
}
```

Which step should I take next? Can I work with annotations without using reflection? Could you expose for me samples of such annotation processing code?

Comment: Next step is to create an annotation processor. Take a look [here](http://programmaticallyspeaking.com/playing-with-java-annotation-processing.html) and [here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/08/java-annotations-explored-explained.html) to see how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way (AFAIK) to work with annotations without reflection.

If you don't want to use any framework, first step is to write kind of proxy class handling the method requests. It is an example of method processing with annotation use over method:

```
public class MyProxy {
       private <T> T getProxy(T t) {
        return (T) Proxy.newProxyInstance(t.getClass().getClassLoader(), new Class<?>[]{MyClass.class},  new MyInvocationHandler(t));
    }
}
```

And then implement InvocationHandler:

```
    public class MyInvocationHandler implements InvocationHandler {

        private Object obj;

        MyInvocationHandler (Object obj) {
            this.obj = obj;
        }

        @Override
        public Object invoke(Object proxy, final Method method, final Object[] args) throws Throwable {
            boolean isNotNull = method.isAnnotationPresent(NotNull.class);

            if (isNotNull) {
    /* process annotated method. Or go through proxy object fields etc.. */

            }
        }
}
```

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what kind of annotation processing you want to do.

Do you want to add a run-time check that will cause your code to crash if `list` is ever null at run time?  For this, reflection will work.

Do you want to add a compile-time check that will reject your code if it cannot prove that `list` is never null at run time?  For this, an annotation processor such as the [Checker Framework](http://CheckerFramework.org/) will work.

Your question does not explain why you don't want to use a framework.  Doing so will save you from re-implementing a lot of functionality that others have already created.